# is there any way to change single or specific component base href path in angular 4

Tags: angular

**Is there any way to change the base href path only for single component in angular 4.**

---

for example
I want load html page with the help of http.get("../../data/upload/sample.html") and this html page contain one image too.
when page is load it's show error http://localhost:4200/doublelink.png 404 (Not Found) but actually image is preset with /data/upload/doublelink.png. i want to set base path for this component which help to load image from the folder.
plz provide solution without change the img src="" path.

Comment: @Vega inside src folder in my projetc

Comment: @Vega Still its not working for me

Comment: 1. are you using angular-cli? 2. what is your base href ?

Comment: Yes..   and i need base href path only for single component.. not for app

Comment: <base href="/">

Comment: it is already there  in angular-cli.json

Comment: yes that's y i can read the html page

Comment: i can't insert 1000 entry of images in assets..

Answer (score 0):

In the .angular-cli json file you can specify where your browser can look for assets.

I.E, mine has the following:

"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "app/headerpage"
      ],

This means I can follow the link http://localhost:4200/assets/doublelink.png OR
http://localhost:4200/headerpage/doublelink.png